# Modify HTA:Application Tag via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, hta

I have tried several things in an attempt to modify the HTA:Application tag via jQuery and it does not seem to work.

imgurl = (path to image)

$('HTA:Application').prop('icon', 'imgurl');
or
$('HTA:Application').attr('icon', 'imgurl');
Does not seem to work. I just don't know if jQuery is not able to modify a HTA tag or if there is another way to implement this, that I cannot find on Google or here.

Comment: maybe `$("HTA\\:Application")`

Comment: Just tried that and it did not work either.

Comment: this is working with lowercase `$('hta\\:application')` : [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hacketo/Lbvx679t/)

Comment: Interesting. This does indeed work inside of a browser, but does not work within a .hta file itself.

Comment: You can't, all the properties of `<HTA:APPLICATION>` are read-only. You've to set the attribute values in the file, they can't be set dynamically.